# JButton does not appear on panel after i invoke the instantiation method

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, jcomponent

Coded this in netbeans so I did not write all the code for the creation of the rest of the GUI myself.

btn_Next is the button that is already on the panel

```
private void place_Button() {

    btn_Next.setLocation((btn_Next.getX()+30), btn_Next.getY());
    btn_Next.revalidate();
    btn_Next.repaint();

    JButton btn_Back = new JButton("Back");
    pnl_Buttons.add(btn_Back);

    btn_Back.setPreferredSize(btn_Next.getPreferredSize());
    btn_Back.setLocation((btn_Next.getX()- 100), btn_Next.getY());
    btn_Back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            switch_Works_Back();
        }
    });

    btn_Back.setVisible(true);
    pnl_Buttons.revalidate();
    pnl_Buttons.repaint();

}
```

Comment: What layout manager does pnl_Buttons use? If you don't know, you could easily have Java print it out: `System.out.println(pnl_Buttons.getLayout());` Note that some layout managers allow adding components much better than others, and for your question, the layout is key.

Answer (score 3):

What layout manager does pnl_Buttons use? If you don't know, you could easily have Java print it out:

```
System.out.println(pnl_Buttons.getLayout());
```

Note that some layout managers allow adding components much better than others, and for your question, the layout is key.

---

A guess here, but it looks like your pnl_Buttons uses a null layout, and if so, your JButton may not be showing because its size is 0 x 0 since you never set its size; this is because null layouts require that the added components specify completely their own size and location. You specify the location and the **preferred** size of the button but not its size. If so, a quick solution is to set the JButton's size via `setSize(...)`, but **much** better is to not use null layouts, and instead use one of the more user friendly layout managers.

As an aside, you shouldn't call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the component being added and don't need to call `setVisible(true)` on your JBUtton unless you've called `setVisible(false)` on it previously. Instead you only need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that you're adding your component to, here your pnl_Buttons object.

Comment: @retroSpect: you're welcome, but again, please do tell us what layout you're using.

Comment: My existing button wont move though

Comment: @retroSpect: any time you wish to answer my questions and provide more detail, we'll be more than willing to try to give you effective help.

Comment: Layout is Free Design. Its the default setting in Netbeans

Comment: @retroSpect: I would recommend that you consider using a layout that more easily will accept new components at run time. Please have a look at the [layout manager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I will definitely try using another layout

Comment: +1 :) *"Layout is Free Design. Its the default setting in Netbeans"* So the layout manager is [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) since you are probably using NetBeans' GUI builder and that's what *Free Design* means actually. If you see generated code you can check this fact. @retroSpect